# How to get data from One table to copy into another table within same database?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a system where User gets the data filtered from user search criteria from database table docs and get data in the table with each row having checklist for each row. When user want to pass the request to process further they check the boxs and send request. I want to grab those requested data and save it to another table called payments within same database.

Here is my view

```
<form  method="POST" >
 @csrf

 <button type="submit" formaction="original_po" name="submit" class="btn btn-success checklistpo">Request Payment</button>
      <div class="table-responsive">

        <table class="table custom-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col" ></th>
              <th scope="col" >S.N</th>
              <th scope="col">LC NO</th>
              <th scope="col">Applicant</th>
              <th scope="col">Doc Value</th>
              <th scope="col">Doc Received date</th>
              <th scope="col">LC Type</th>
              
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <?php $number = 1;?>
            @foreach($datas as $items)
              
            <tr>
              
              <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist[]" value="{{$items->id}}" /></td>
              <td>{{$number}}</td>
              <td>{{$items->lc_no}}</td>
              <td>{{$items->applicant}}</td>
              <td>{{$items->doc_value}}</td>
              <td>{{$items->rec_date}}</td>
              <td>{{$items->sight_usance}}</td>                  


            </tr>
            <?php $number++; ?>
            @endforeach
         
            
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      </form>
```

Here is the controller

```
  function original_list_request(Request $req){
        $validate = Validator::make($req->all(), [
        "checkboxlist" => "required|array"
    ]);

    if ($validate->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->with("errors", $validate->errors());
    }
    $payment_data = new Payment;
    
    foreach ($req->checkboxlist as $list) {
        $data = Doc::find($list);
        $list= $payment_data->org_document_id;
        $data->lc_no= $payment_data->lc_no;
        $data->doc_value = $payment_data->payment_amount;
        $data->Payment_status = "Payment Requested";
        $payment_data->payment_type = "Original";
        $payment_data->save();
        $data->save();


    }


    }
```

my doc Schema

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('docs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('lc_no')->nullable();
            $table->string('nb_ref')->nullable();
            $table->string('nego_bank')->nullable();
            $table->string('doc_value')->nullable();
            $table->string('applicant')->nullable();
            $table->string('sight_usance')->nullable();
            $table->string('sol_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('con_lc')->nullable();
            $table->date('rec_date')->nullable();
            $table->string('bene')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->nullable();
            $table->string('cur')->nullable();
            $table->string('doclot')->nullable();
            $table->string('check_staus')->nullable();
            $table->string('doc_type')->nullable();
            $table->string('cln_dis')->nullable();
            $table->string('status')->nullable();
            $table->date('maturity_date')->nullable();
            $table->date('pmt_msg_date')->nullable();
            $table->date('value_date')->nullable();
            $table->date('settlement_date')->nullable();
            $table->date('acceptance_date')->nullable();
            $table->date('hold_date')->nullable();
            $table->string('payment_status')->nullable();
            $table->string('maturity_status')->nullable();
            $table->string('entered_by')->nullable();
            $table->string('verified_by')->nullable();
            $table->string('doc_comment')->nullable();
            $table->string('settlement_comment')->nullable();
            $table->string('payment_comment')->nullable();
            $table->string('treasury_comment')->nullable();
            $table->string('hold_comment')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

my payment schema

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('org_document_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('lc_no')->nullable();
            $table->string('payment_amount')->nullable();
            $table->string('payment_status')->nullable();
            $table->string('payment_type')->nullable();
            $table->string('msg_type')->nullable();
            $table->string('other')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: can you mention what error  you get in current code

Comment: i am not getting error but not updating in payment table @JohnLobo

Comment: foreach ($req->checkboxlist as $list) {
        $data = Doc::find($list);
        
        $payment_data = new Payment;
        $payment_data->org_document_id=$data->org_document_id;
        $payment_data->lc_no= $data->lc_no;
        $payment_data->doc_value = $data->payment_amount;
        $payment_data->Payment_status = "Payment Requested";
        $payment_data->payment_type = "Original";
        $payment_data->save();
        
    }

Comment: i am only updating payment_type as original but not getting other data like lc_no and other datas @JohnLobo

Comment: can you show both table schema and explain what field you have update while submitting.Also check dd($request->all());

Comment: I edited my question ...@JohnLobo with schema